# building html table using array containing csv data in javascript

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm getting csv data from an S3 object and converting it to a string using the code shown below, then I'm dumping the string into an array arr thinking I can build a html table using `<tr>` and `<td>` tags which include data that I got from csv, when I try below I'm not getting desirable output in JavaScript

```
let s3obj = new AWS.S3();
var arr = [];
var html = '<table>';
let s3param = {
      Bucket: 'test-bucket',
      Key: 'test-csv-file'
      };
      s3obj.getObject(s3param, function(err, data){
        if(err){
          throw err;
      } else {
         const body = Buffer.from(data.Body).toString('utf8'); //when i did console.log(typeof(body)) i get string datatype
         arr = body; //i tried converting string into array

    //below is the data i got back when i console.log(arr);

    //TEST,ROW,NUMBER,1
    //TEST,ROW,NUMBER,2
    //TEST,ROW,NUMBER,3

//below code tries to work on Array arr to get the output following it written into htmlTable variable

 for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      htmlTable += '<tr>';
       for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        htmlTable += '<td>';
        htmlTable += arr[i][j];
        htmlTable += '</td>';
        }
     htmlTable += '<tr>';
    }
//<table>
   // <tr><td>TEST</td><td>ROW</td><td>NUMBER</td><td>1</td></tr>
   // <tr><td>TEST</td><td>ROW</td><td>NUMBER</td><td>2</td></tr>   
   // <tr><td>TEST</td><td>ROW</td><td>NUMBER</td><td>3</td></tr>
   // <tr><td>TEST</td><td>ROW</td><td>NUMBER</td><td>4</td></tr>
//</table>
```

Instead of the above output I'm getting something else. Not sure where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate help in building html table just like above.

Comment: what format is `data.Body` in when it originally comes back?

Comment: when i output `data` argument i see `ContentType: "application/octet-stream`

Comment: I was wondering what format the data body is in, not the object type of data.

Comment: sorry, i looked for any property to get out but cannot seem to find one

Comment: As in what happens when you `console.log(data.Body)`, thats all im i asking

Comment: so, when i try `console.log(data.Body);` i don't see anything coming out

Comment: Is your code identical to what you posted above?  Because youre missing a tick mark at the end of your Key property in s3param

Comment: i just added that tick, In my original code I'm using Lambda ENV Variables, i have the code working till getting the CSV output as stated above. Having challenge to convert the output for local use in the Lambda function

Comment: Could you  be more precise what `body` is? Is it a multiline string, an array of strings, or a nested array? Please provide the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(body))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the structure of `body`, you would do one of the following:

1. If it is an array of strings with commas:

   ```
   arr = body.map(line => line.split(","));
   ```
2. If it is a single string with newlines and commas:

   ```
   arr = body.match(/.*/g).map(line => line.split(","));
   ```

Comment: Thanks @trincot, I'm getting single string with newlines and commas as response, Array arr now prints the values as expected, appreciate your time.